# How do I recover CIPCODE string values when data was exported to .csv as numbers?

Tags: collegescorecard

I'm trying to download the CIPCODES from file c2015_a.csv, but the csv file shows them as a number rather than a string.  That means the ##.#### formatting is already gone before I can do anything with it.  This results in some majors such as "16.03" (East Asian Languages, Literatures, and Linguistics) viewed as the same thing as "16.0300" (East Asian Languages, Literatures, and Linguistics, General.).  There are a number of instances where this happens.

It seems to me that there is no way to recover the data I'm looking for and that CIPCODES would need to be exported from the source as a string.  Is this right?

Info I'm looking for came from download for: Awards/degrees conferred by program (6-digit CIP code), award level, race/ethnicity, and gender: July 1, 2014 to June 30, 2015

Comment: It certainly sounds like some data was lost here.  Your idea that CIPCODES would need to be exported from the source as a string sounds right.  Can you share the direct link?

Comment: Hi Dan-  The link is http://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/DataFiles.aspx but navigation is tricky from this point.  Somehow I get to a screen that has "Complete Data Files" header and then a tab that says "Years & Surveys" with a "Continue Button"  However the file I'm using is called c2015_a.csv for year-->2015 and survey-->completions.